# D3 + Angular 4 + chrome not able to read JSON file from local IP

Tags: angular, google-chrome, d3.js

Angular 4 app is hosted on https://192.168.1.104:xxxx and accessed by providing Basic authentication credentials.

The following code snippet is used to read JSON file of US states' border coordinates and plot them using D3.

```
D3.json("/assets/topojson/us.json", function (error, us: any) {
            self.mapUSGroup.append("path")
                .attr("class", "state")
                .datum(Topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states))
                .attr("d", self.projectionPath);
        });
```

It reads the file when used on Firefox but on Chrome it gives the following console error and asks for authentication again.

```
GET https://null:null@192.168.1.104:20043/assets/topojson/us.json 401 (Unauthorized)
```

It was working fine on Angular 2. It works fine for external IP.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It is cleary visible that you are not sending credentials in the request url and you are getting a 401

Comment: OK. I provide it when the app loads for the first time and rest of the app loads as usual from https://192.168.1.104:xxxx. The same credentials was reused automatically by Angular 2 (then) and FF(now). It asks for credentials again only on Chrome and Angular 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems related to
["HTTP Basic Authentication credentials in Google Chrome 64 not transfered to AJAX calls in d3.js"](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/83741)

which states

> started with Google Chrome 64 which had some changes regarding the handling of basic auth credentials in URLs.